# Why does Dijkstra's algorithm need to use the deleteMin() and decreaseKey()?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, computer-science, dijkstra

In most pieces of pseudocode, I usually find the following:

> - DeleteMin (Return the element with the smallest key and delete it from the set.)
> - DecreaseKey (Accomodate the decrease in key value of a particular element)

- Why is DeleteMin being used to retrieve the smallest element- why not a random one?
- What is the purpose of DecreaseKey? In pseudocode it's always called after the value of an element is changed. What is it doing?

Comment: Are you talking about a [heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)), rather than Dijkstra's algorithm?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does Dijkstra's algorithm use decrease-key?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9255620/why-does-dijkstras-algorithm-use-decrease-key)

Comment: If you take a random next node(not with the smallest distance) the algorithm is incorrect.

Comment: No, Dijkstra's algorithm uses a priority que, which is often confused with a heap. I am asking specifically about the function of the above instructions in the context of Dijkstra's algorithm.

Comment: @PetarMinchev Why would it be incorrect? How does it matter in which order to readjust the key values?

Comment: I am talking about that at each step you take the closest node and update the neighbours.

Comment: @PetarMinchev: I disagree it is a dupe. The other question specifically asks: why don't we *re-add v*, while this question asks - why modify in the first place? It also asks about the deleteMin() step, which is happening much before the modification.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why is DeleteMin being used to retrieve the smallest element- why not
>   a random one?

We retrieve and delete the min elements from `Q` the set of
   open vertices because it ensures minimality (later used in the proof).
   Without it - the minimality feature is not guaranteed, and the solution will not be optimal (won't be the shortest path). Remember that once we found a path to `v`, we remove it from `Q`, and will never re-open it, so the edge we take out must have the one with the smallest path available.

Note that for this (the minimal) vertex, let it be `v`: for each `u` in `Q` `d(u) + x <= d(v)` - since dijkstra's algorithm is used when there are no negative edges, x >=0.

**For any other vertex - which is not minimal - we cannot guarantee that there is no shorter path yet to be discovered.**

> What is the purpose of DecreaseKey? In pseudocode it's always called
>   after the value of an element is changed. What is it doing?

The decrease is used because we might have found a new, better path to vertices that are connected to the last vertex we found. **This step is the relaxation step dijkstra's algorithm is making.** Remember that dijkstra's algorithm is always maintaining the shortest path found so far to each vertex, since the last step might have found a new shortest path to some vertex - this step is updating the shortest path found so far.