# Scala: can PriorityQueue.update be used efficiently to decrease keys?

Tags: scala, priority-queue

Priority queues support a 'decrease key' operation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue#Summary_of_running_times), it is needed for a number of best first search type algorithms. It should run in O(log n) time. Does scala.collection.mutable.PriorityQueue support this efficiently?

Looking through the API docs the closest thing I can find is

```
def update (idx: Int, elem: A) : Unit
Replaces element at given index with a new value.
```

But there are two potential problems with this… firstly one has to find the element and it's not clear what the time complexity of `findIndexOf` is.* Second it looks like `update` allows the value to be increased as well as decreased; it's not clear whether that can be implemented efficiently.

*See e.g. [How to implement O(logn) decrease-key operation for min-heap based Priority Queue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17009056/how-to-implement-ologn-decrease-key-operation-for-min-heap-based-priority-queu) for proof that this can be done efficiently.

Does anyone know what the time complexity of update is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`scala.collection.mutable.PriorityQueue` does not support a `decrease-key` operation.

To implement a `PQ` with `decrease-key` operation, one must augment a typical `PQ` implementation with an additional data structure for indexing.

The accepted answer to the post you reference, [How to implement O(logn) decrease-key operation for min-heap based Priority Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17009056/how-to-implement-ologn-decrease-key-operation-for-min-heap-based-priority-queu), illustrates how to do this.

The Java standard library also does not contain an indexed priority queue.

You can find one Java implemenation on the [Princeton Algorithms](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/24pq/IndexMinPQ.java.html) site.

There is a Scala version of the above located [here](https://github.com/garyaiki/Scala-Algorithms/blob/master/src/main/scala/org/gs/queue/IndexPriorityQueue.scala)