# Priority Queue that uses a comparator and has decrease key operation

Tags: java, data-structures, priority-queue

So I have a problem where I have a set of objects with two fields. I need to be able to get the min object of the set at a fast time time (using a custom comparator). The problem is, when I get the min object set, it changes the fields of some objects in my original set. Thus, the ordering of the set needs to be changed when I am done with the min object.

To me it seems obvious to use a priority queue with a custom comparator, the problem is, the Priority Queue in Java doesn't have a change or decrease key operation. I have tried looking for other implementations online for a priority queue that uses a comparator with the decrease key operation but I cannot find one. Any help would be greatly appreciated as to how to approach this problem? Is there another data structure I can use?

Below is my adaptation of what I am talking about.It is a bit hackish and I have found it doesn't work properly, as I have found in testing the ordering of adding elements into the queue somehow affects the ordering of the priority queue itself. I am not looking for help on this specific code as it will be most likely tossed.

```
**
 * A class representing a Fibonacci heap.
 *
 * @param T The type of elements to store in the heap.
 * @author Keith Schwarz (htiek@cs.stanford.edu)
 */
public final class FibonacciHeap<T> {
    /* In order for all of the Fibonacci heap operations to complete in O(1),
     * clients need to have O(1) access to any element in the heap.  We make
     * this work by having each insertion operation produce a handle to the
     * node in the tree.  In actuality, this handle is the node itself, but
     * we guard against external modification by marking the internal fields
     * private.
     */
    public static final class Entry<T> {
        private int     mDegree = 0;       // Number of children
        private boolean mIsMarked = false; // Whether this node is marked

        private Entry<T> mNext;   // Next and previous elements in the list
        private Entry<T> mPrev;

        private Entry<T> mParent; // Parent in the tree, if any.

        private Entry<T> mChild;  // Child node, if any.

        private T      mElem;     // Element being stored here
        private int mPriority; // Its priority

        /**
         * Returns the element represented by this heap entry.
         *
         * @return The element represented by this heap entry.
         */
        public T getValue() {
            return mElem;
        }
        /**
         * Sets the element associated with this heap entry.
         *
         * @param value The element to associate with this heap entry.
         */
        public void setValue(T value) {
            mElem = value;
        }

        /**
         * Returns the priority of this element.
         *
         * @return The priority of this element.
         */
        public int getPriority() {
            return mPriority;
        }

        /**
         * Constructs a new Entry that holds the given element with the indicated
         * priority.
         *
         * @param elem The element stored in this node.
         * @param priority The priority of this element.
         */
        private Entry(T elem, int priority) {
            mNext = mPrev = this;
            mElem = elem;
            mPriority = priority;
        }
    }

    /* Pointer to the minimum element in the heap. */
    private Entry<T> mMin = null;

    /* Cached size of the heap, so we don't have to recompute this explicitly. */
    private int mSize = 0;

    /**
     * Inserts the specified element into the Fibonacci heap with the specified
     * priority.  Its priority must be a valid double, so you cannot set the
     * priority to NaN.
     *
     * @param value The value to insert.
     * @param priority Its priority, which must be valid.
     * @return An Entry representing that element in the tree.
     */
    public Entry<T> enqueue(T value, int priority) {
        /* Create the entry object, which is a circularly-linked list of length
         * one.
         */
        Entry<T> result = new Entry<T>(value, priority);

        /* Merge this singleton list with the tree list. */
        mMin = mergeLists(mMin, result);

        /* Increase the size of the heap; we just added something. */
        ++mSize;

        /* Return the reference to the new element. */
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Returns an Entry object corresponding to the minimum element of the
     * Fibonacci heap, throwing a NoSuchElementException if the heap is
     * empty.
     *
     * @return The smallest element of the heap.
     * @throws NoSuchElementException If the heap is empty.
     */
    public Entry<T> min() {
        if (isEmpty())
            throw new NoSuchElementException("Heap is empty.");
        return mMin;
    }

    /**
     * Returns whether the heap is empty.
     *
     * @return Whether the heap is empty.
     */
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return mMin == null;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the number of elements in the heap.
     *
     * @return The number of elements in the heap.
     */
    public int size() {
        return mSize;
    }

    /**
     * Given two Fibonacci heaps, returns a new Fibonacci heap that contains
     * all of the elements of the two heaps.  Each of the input heaps is
     * destructively modified by having all its elements removed.  You can
     * continue to use those heaps, but be aware that they will be empty
     * after this call completes.
     *
     * @param one The first Fibonacci heap to merge.
     * @param two The second Fibonacci heap to merge.
     * @return A new FibonacciHeap containing all of the elements of both
     *         heaps.
     */
    public static <T> FibonacciHeap<T> merge(FibonacciHeap<T> one, FibonacciHeap<T> two) {
        /* Create a new FibonacciHeap to hold the result. */
        FibonacciHeap<T> result = new FibonacciHeap<T>();

        /* Merge the two Fibonacci heap root lists together.  This helper function
         * also computes the min of the two lists, so we can store the result in
         * the mMin field of the new heap.
         */
        result.mMin = mergeLists(one.mMin, two.mMin);

        /* The size of the new heap is the sum of the sizes of the input heaps. */
        result.mSize = one.mSize + two.mSize;

        /* Clear the old heaps. */
        one.mSize = two.mSize = 0;
        one.mMin  = null;
        two.mMin  = null;

        /* Return the newly-merged heap. */
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Dequeues and returns the minimum element of the Fibonacci heap.  If the
     * heap is empty, this throws a NoSuchElementException.
     *
     * @return The smallest element of the Fibonacci heap.
     * @throws NoSuchElementException If the heap is empty.
     */
    public Entry<T> dequeueMin() {
        /* Check for whether we're empty. */
        if (isEmpty())
            throw new NoSuchElementException("Heap is empty.");

        /* Otherwise, we're about to lose an element, so decrement the number of
         * entries in this heap.
         */
        --mSize;

        /* Grab the minimum element so we know what to return. */
        Entry<T> minElem = mMin;

        /* Now, we need to get rid of this element from the list of roots.  There
         * are two cases to consider.  First, if this is the only element in the
         * list of roots, we set the list of roots to be null by clearing mMin.
         * Otherwise, if it's not null, then we write the elements next to the
         * min element around the min element to remove it, then arbitrarily
         * reassign the min.
         */
        if (mMin.mNext == mMin) { // Case one
            mMin = null;
        }
        else { // Case two
            mMin.mPrev.mNext = mMin.mNext;
            mMin.mNext.mPrev = mMin.mPrev;
            mMin = mMin.mNext; // Arbitrary element of the root list.
        }

        /* Next, clear the parent fields of all of the min element's children,
         * since they're about to become roots.  Because the elements are
         * stored in a circular list, the traversal is a bit complex.
         */
        if (minElem.mChild != null) {
            /* Keep track of the first visited node. */
            Entry<?> curr = minElem.mChild;
            do {
                curr.mParent = null;

                /* Walk to the next node, then stop if this is the node we
                 * started at.
                 */
                curr = curr.mNext;
            } while (curr != minElem.mChild);
        }

        /* Next, splice the children of the root node into the topmost list,
         * then set mMin to point somewhere in that list.
         */
        mMin = mergeLists(mMin, minElem.mChild);

        /* If there are no entries left, we're done. */
        if (mMin == null) return minElem;

        /* Next, we need to coalsce all of the roots so that there is only one
         * tree of each degree.  To track trees of each size, we allocate an
         * ArrayList where the entry at position i is either null or the
         * unique tree of degree i.
         */
        List<Entry<T>> treeTable = new ArrayList<Entry<T>>();

        /* We need to traverse the entire list, but since we're going to be
         * messing around with it we have to be careful not to break our
         * traversal order mid-stream.  One major challenge is how to detect
         * whether we're visiting the same node twice.  To do this, we'll
         * spent a bit of overhead adding all of the nodes to a list, and
         * then will visit each element of this list in order.
         */
        List<Entry<T>> toVisit = new ArrayList<Entry<T>>();

        /* To add everything, we'll iterate across the elements until we
         * find the first element twice.  We check this by looping while the
         * list is empty or while the current element isn't the first element
         * of that list.
         */
        for (Entry<T> curr = mMin; toVisit.isEmpty() || toVisit.get(0) != curr; curr = curr.mNext)
            toVisit.add(curr);

        /* Traverse this list and perform the appropriate unioning steps. */
        for (Entry<T> curr: toVisit) {
            /* Keep merging until a match arises. */
            while (true) {
                /* Ensure that the list is long enough to hold an element of this
                 * degree.
                 */
                while (curr.mDegree >= treeTable.size())
                    treeTable.add(null);

                /* If nothing's here, we're can record that this tree has this size
                 * and are done processing.
                 */
                if (treeTable.get(curr.mDegree) == null) {
                    treeTable.set(curr.mDegree, curr);
                    break;
                }

                /* Otherwise, merge with what's there. */
                Entry<T> other = treeTable.get(curr.mDegree);
                treeTable.set(curr.mDegree, null); // Clear the slot

                /* Determine which of the two trees has the smaller root, storing
                 * the two tree accordingly.
                 */
                //TODO Test
                Entry<T> min = (((Comparable<T>)other.mElem).compareTo(curr.mElem) < -1)? other : curr;
                Entry<T> max = (((Comparable<T>)other.mElem).compareTo(curr.mElem) < -1)? curr  : other;

                /* Break max out of the root list, then merge it into min's child
                 * list.
                 */
                max.mNext.mPrev = max.mPrev;
                max.mPrev.mNext = max.mNext;

                /* Make it a singleton so that we can merge it. */
                max.mNext = max.mPrev = max;
                min.mChild = mergeLists(min.mChild, max);

                /* Reparent max appropriately. */
                max.mParent = min;

                /* Clear max's mark, since it can now lose another child. */
                max.mIsMarked = false;

                /* Increase min's degree; it now has another child. */
                ++min.mDegree;

                /* Continue merging this tree. */
                curr = min;
            }

            /* Update the global min based on this node.  Note that we compare
             * for <= instead of < here.  That's because if we just did a
             * reparent operation that merged two different trees of equal
             * priority, we need to make sure that the min pointer points to
             * the root-level one.
             */
            if (((Comparable<T>)curr.mElem).compareTo(mMin.mElem) < 1){
                mMin = curr;
            }
        }
        return minElem;
    }

    /**
     * Decreases the key of the specified element to the new priority.  If the
     * new priority is greater than the old priority, this function throws an
     * IllegalArgumentException.  The new priority must be a finite double,
     * so you cannot set the priority to be NaN, or +/- infinity.  Doing
     * so also throws an IllegalArgumentException.
     *
     * It is assumed that the entry belongs in this heap.  For efficiency
     * reasons, this is not checked at runtime.
     *
     * @param entry The element whose priority should be decreased.
     * @param newPriority The new priority to associate with this entry.
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException If the new priority exceeds the old
     *         priority, or if the argument is not a finite double.
     */
    public void decreaseKey(Entry<T> entry, int newPriority) {
        if (newPriority > entry.mPriority)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("New priority exceeds old.");

        /* Forward this to a helper function. */
        decreaseKeyUnchecked(entry, newPriority);
    }

    /**
     * Deletes this Entry from the Fibonacci heap that contains it.
     *!!!
     * It is assumed that the entry belongs in this heap.  For efficiency
     * reasons, this is not checked at runtime.
     *
     * @param entry The entry to delete.
     */
    public void delete(Entry<T> entry) {
        /* Use decreaseKey to drop the entry's key to -infinity.  This will
         * guarantee that the node is cut and set to the global minimum.
         */
        decreaseKeyUnchecked(entry, Integer.MIN_VALUE);

        /* Call dequeueMin to remove it. */
        dequeueMin();
    }


    /**
     * Utility function which, given two pointers into disjoint circularly-
     * linked lists, merges the two lists together into one circularly-linked
     * list in O(1) time.  Because the lists may be empty, the return value
     * is the only pointer that's guaranteed to be to an element of the
     * resulting list.
     *
     * This function assumes that one and two are the minimum elements of the
     * lists they are in, and returns a pointer to whichever is smaller.  If
     * this condition does not hold, the return value is some arbitrary pointer
     * into the doubly-linked list.
     *
     * @param one A pointer into one of the two linked lists.
     * @param two A pointer into the other of the two linked lists.
     * @return A pointer to the smallest element of the resulting list.
     */
    private static <T> Entry<T> mergeLists(Entry<T> one, Entry<T> two) {
        /* There are four cases depending on whether the lists are null or not.
         * We consider each separately.
         */
        if (one == null && two == null) { // Both null, resulting list is null.
            return null;
        }
        else if (one != null && two == null) { // Two is null, result is one.
            return one;
        }
        else if (one == null && two != null) { // One is null, result is two.
            return two;
        }
        else { // Both non-null; actually do the splice.
            /* This is actually not as easy as it seems.  The idea is that we'll
             * have two lists that look like this:
             *
             * +----+     +----+     +----+
             * |    |--N->|one |--N->|    |
             * |    |<-P--|    |<-P--|    |
             * +----+     +----+     +----+
             *
             *
             * +----+     +----+     +----+
             * |    |--N->|two |--N->|    |
             * |    |<-P--|    |<-P--|    |
             * +----+     +----+     +----+
             *
             * And we want to relink everything to get
             *
             * +----+     +----+     +----+---+
             * |    |--N->|one |     |    |   |
             * |    |<-P--|    |     |    |<+ |
             * +----+     +----+<-\  +----+ | |
             *                  \  P        | |
             *                   N  \       N |
             * +----+     +----+  \->+----+ | |
             * |    |--N->|two |     |    | | |
             * |    |<-P--|    |     |    | | P
             * +----+     +----+     +----+ | |
             *              ^ |             | |
             *              | +-------------+ |
             *              +-----------------+
             *
             */
            Entry<T> oneNext = one.mNext; // Cache this since we're about to overwrite it.
            one.mNext = two.mNext;
            one.mNext.mPrev = one;
            two.mNext = oneNext;
            two.mNext.mPrev = two;

            /* Return a pointer to whichever's smaller. */
            return ((Comparable<T>)one.mElem).compareTo(two.mElem) < 0? one : two;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Decreases the key of a node in the tree without doing any checking to ensure
     * that the new priority is valid. This method does not modify and members in the
     * entry objects element.
     *
     * @param entry The node whose key should be decreased.
     * @param priority The node's new priority.
     */
    private void decreaseKeyUnchecked(Entry<T> entry, int priority) {
        /* First, change the node's priority. */
        entry.mPriority = priority;
        ((GNode)entry.mElem).setInE(priority);

        /* If the node no longer has a higher priority than its parent, cut it.
         * Note that this also means that if we try to run a delete operation
         * that decreases the key to -infinity, it's guaranteed to cut the node
         * from its parent.
         */
        if (entry.mParent != null && ((GNode)entry.mElem).compareTo((GNode)entry.mParent.mElem) <= 0)
            cutNode(entry);

        /* If our new value is the new min, mark it as such.  Note that if we
         * ended up decreasing the key in a way that ties the current minimum
         * priority, this will change the min accordingly.
         */
        //NPE fix If mMin in null, means we have only one entry left... and we swap
        if (mMin == null || ((GNode)entry.mElem).compareTo((GNode)mMin.mElem) <= 0)
            mMin = entry;
    }

    /**
     * Cuts a node from its parent.  If the parent was already marked, recursively
     * cuts that node from its parent as well.
     *
     * @param entry The node to cut from its parent.
     */
    private void cutNode(Entry<T> entry) {
        /* Begin by clearing the node's mark, since we just cut it. */
        entry.mIsMarked = false;

        /* Base case: If the node has no parent, we're done. */
        if (entry.mParent == null) return;

        /* Rewire the node's siblings around it, if it has any siblings. */
        if (entry.mNext != entry) { // Has siblings
            entry.mNext.mPrev = entry.mPrev;
            entry.mPrev.mNext = entry.mNext;
        }

        /* If the node is the one identified by its parent as its child,
         * we need to rewrite that pointer to point to some arbitrary other
         * child.
         */
        if (entry.mParent.mChild == entry) {
            /* If there are any other children, pick one of them arbitrarily. */
            if (entry.mNext != entry) {
                entry.mParent.mChild = entry.mNext;
            }
            /* Otherwise, there aren't any children left and we should clear the
             * pointer and drop the node's degree.
             */
            else {
                entry.mParent.mChild = null;
            }
        }

        /* Decrease the degree of the parent, since it just lost a child. */
        --entry.mParent.mDegree;

        /* Splice this tree into the root list by converting it to a singleton
         * and invoking the merge subroutine.
         */
        entry.mPrev = entry.mNext = entry;
        mMin = mergeLists(mMin, entry);

        /* Mark the parent and recursively cut it if it's already been
         * marked.
         */
        if (entry.mParent.mIsMarked)
            cutNode(entry.mParent);
        else
            entry.mParent.mIsMarked = true;

        /* Clear the relocated node's parent; it's now a root. */
        entry.mParent = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does *"a change or decrease key operation"* mean? Are you asking for a **descending** ordering? Maps and Priority Queues and such cannot handle the *changing* of the key fields of the object. If a field is changed, the object must be removed (before changing the field) and re-added (after changing the field).

Comment: @Andreas some priority queues do support this "change key" operation. But if you can recommend a DS that can do what you are saying that would be great.

Comment: @BoredPerson The standard PrriorityQueue class can do that. You can just pass the comparator you want.

Comment: @JBNizet PriorityQueue cannot handle the changing of fields used by Comparator given to PriorityQueue, i.e. it cannot handle the "changing of keys".

Comment: @Andreas I am literally asking for a data structure... or recommendation for another one. It just happens to be the Java standard PQ doesn't support a change in key operation.

Comment: @BoredPerson sorry, I misinterpreted your previous comment. I thought you were asking Andreas to recommend a DS that can do "a descending ordering".

Comment: @BoredPerson Since any data structure that can provide quick access to "smallest value" must store the data in some organized fashion, it simply cannot continue to work if the data is changed without the data structure being notified so it can adjust the internal organization accordingly. Since Java doesn't have such built-in notification support, what you're asking is impossible. When a key property of an object is modified, the data structure *must* be notified. For the standard data structures in Java, you do that by removing and re-adding the object, as I've already mentioned.

Comment: @Andreas Given that the data structure I am looking for is the one preferably used in Dijkstra's algorithm and can many adaptations can be found by googling "Priority queue with decrease-key operation", I find it hard to believe it is impossible.

Comment: @BoredPerson If you already found answers on the web with the algorithm you're looking for, why are you asking for it? If you want to write a data structure with a `changeKey(E element, K newKey)` method, then wrap PriorityQueue, and implement the method as `queue.remove(element); element.setKey(newKey); queue.add(element);`.

Comment: Take a look at this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/17581306 it might be useful.

Comment: When I write Dijkstra's algorithm or similar in Java, I usually put separate (key,element) values in the PriorityQueue.  When the key decreases for an element I just insert a new value, and when I pop vertexes off the queue I ignore ones that have already been done, so the values with higher keys are harmless.  This changes the space complexity to O(|E|) from O(|V|), but that's not usually a big deal, and the time complexity stays the same.