# Dijkstra shortest path algorith performance of std::priority_queue Vs std::set

Tags: c++, algorithm, performance, graph, stl

I would like to understand the main difference of these containers regarding their time complexity. 
I've tried 3 implementations of Dijkstra algorithm as described below:

1- with a simple array used as queue

2- with STL priority_queue

3- with STL set

the graph I've tested is quite big, it contains more than 150000 vertices, oriented and all the weight of the edges are positive.

the results I get are the following:

1 - with array the algorithm is pretty slow --> which is expected

2 - with STL priority_queue the algorithm run a lot faster than the array --> which is also expected

3 - with STL set the algorithm run incredibly fast, I'm talking about couple 100 times faster than the priority_queue --> I didn't expect to see this huge performance...

knowing that the std::priority_queue and std::set are data containers that store elements and both have basically the same insertion complexity O(log n), I don't understand this big performance difference between them.  Have you any explanation about this?

thanks for your help,

**Edited:** 
here it is an abstract of my implementations:

with std::set:

```
unsigned int Graphe::dijkstra(size_t p_source, size_t p_destination) const {

....


set<pair<int, size_t>> set_vertices;


vector<unsigned int> distance(listAdj.size(),
        numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max());


vector < size_t
        > predecessor(listAdj.size(),
                numeric_limits < size_t > ::max());


distance[p_source] = 0;
set_vertices.insert( { 0, p_source });


while (!set_vertices.empty()) {

    unsigned int u = set_vertices.begin()->second;


    if (u == p_destination) {
        break;
    }

    set_vertices.erase( { distance[u],
            u });


    for (auto itr = listAdj[u].begin();
            itr != listAdj[u].end(); ++itr) {


        int v = itr->destination;
        int weigth = itr->weigth;


        if (distance[v]
                > distance[u] + weigth) {


            if (distance[v]
                    != numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max()) {
                set_vertices.erase(
                        set_vertices.find(
                                make_pair(distance[v],
                                        v)));
            }

            distance[v] = distance[u] + weigth;

            set_vertices.insert( { distance[v],
                    v });

            predecessor[v] = u;
        }
    }
}

....

return distance[p_destination];}
```

and with priority_queue:

```
unsigned int Graphe::dijkstra(size_t p_source, size_t p_destination) const {

...

typedef pair<size_t, int> newpair;

priority_queue<newpair, vector<newpair>, greater<newpair> > PQ;

vector<unsigned int> distance(listAdj.size(),
        numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max());


vector < size_t
        > predecessor(listAdj.size(),
                numeric_limits < size_t > ::max());


distance[p_source] = 0;
PQ.push(make_pair(p_source, 0));

while (!PQ.empty()) {


    unsigned int u = PQ.top().first;


    if (u == p_destination) {
        break;
    }

    PQ.pop();


    for (auto itr = listAdj[u].begin();
            itr != listAdj[u].end(); ++itr) {


        int v = itr->destination;
        int weigth = itr->weigth;


        if (distance[v]
                > distance[u] + weigth) {

            distance[v] = distance[u] + weigth;

            PQ.push(
                    make_pair(v, distance[v]));

            predecessor[v] = u;
        }
    }
}
...

return distance[p_destination];}
```

Comment: Is your implementation correct?

Comment: yeah, I believe it's correct, I get the same output (same pathfinding) in the three implementations. except for the running time which super fast in the third implementation.

Comment: Show us your implementation

Comment: Huge difference between `priority_queue` and `set` could be caused by updating vertices distance step. You can simply update distance using `set`, but you can't do it with `priority_queue` without, for examle, adding same vertex several times with different distances.

Comment: yeah, makes sense, this was my assumption too, since the huge loss of priority_queue happens at the **pop** step of the first element within the queue, it takes a complexity of O(log(size_queue))

Answer (score 2):

### SKIP

You are doubling up on the work really badly with the priority queue.

You are double inserting into the queue, because you can't modify or delete. That's normal and necessary, because you can't.

but then when those old values come out of the queue you need to "skip that iteration of the  while loop".

Something like:

```
if (PQ.top().second != distance[PQ.top().first]) continue;  // It's stale! SKIP!!
```

Comment: What are stale nodes? Is this correct: as we process the neighbours of a node X, we may find a distance to a node Z that is less than what has been recorded. So we update the recorded distances and push the new {node Z, distance to Z} ** onto the PQ. However, before that node is processed in a future iteration, we process the neighbours of node Y and find that the distance to Z is less than the just immediately recorded distance; so again, we update the record and push {node Z, distance to Z} onto the queue. However, the previously added item ** is still in the PQ. It is stale.

Comment: Therefore, to be optimal, we should only process items {node i, distance i} from the PQ that have distance i equal to the distance in the recorded distance array (that is distance[i]). This recorded distance array contains the most up to date (shortest) distances found so far. Please let me know if my understanding is correct. I believe this is the same as what is discussed in the comments here: https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/118406/141696

Comment: Yes, that's all correct. Except that you don't need to check  `PQ.top().second > dist[PQ.top().first]` and simply `!=` will do, and is often slightly faster. This is because stale items coming out of the queue can only ever be `>`, they cannot be `<` by the nature of the way the queue is sorted and the way new, shorter paths are found and inserted. And yes the discussion at your links is about the same thing.

Answer (score -2):

The underlying data-structure of `std::priority_queue` is a max-heap and for `std::set` its self-balanced binary search - basically a red-black tree for C++. So both of them ensures `O(logn)` time complexity in insertion, deletion and update operation.

But, as I mentioned the balanced binary search tree of `std::set` is being balanced automatically to keep its height logarithmic of number of nodes which ensures logarithmic query complexity irrespective of insertion order or after any operations. `std::priority_queue` is not self-balanced and can be very flat depending on insertion order. Although the self-balancing has it's own cost and so as of heapify after removing top, I think that's the reason for the performance gain.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Heap is a complete binary tree, it cannot be 'very flat depending on insertion order'