# Does A* search need a decrease-key operation?

Tags: algorithm, a-star

Dijkstra's shortest-path algorithm requires a priority queue with a decrease-key operation, as noted in the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) and the [C++ Boost Graph Library pseudocode](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/libs/graph/doc/dijkstra_shortest_paths.html).

Neither of these sources indicates whether the priority queue used in A* search requires the decrease-key operation ([Wikpedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm), [C++ Boost](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/libs/graph/doc/astar_search.html)). But the pseudocode in the Wikipedia article includes the line `fScore[neighbor] := tentative_gScore + h(neighbor)`, which seems like it would impact the ordering of elements in the priority queue.

I'm aware that technically, the decrease-key operation isn't necessary even in Dijkstra, with the same functionality achievable through [just reinserting with the node with a lower key and keeping track of what vertices have been expanded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9255620/why-does-dijkstras-algorithm-use-decrease-key). But is this necessary at all in A* search (assuming an admissible and consistent heuristic), i.e. if I don't want to re-insert nodes, do I have to implement the decrease-key operation?

Comment: I think you need to better define what you're interested in. It's not necessary for either Djikstra or A* for the reason you mentioned: you can just use insertions.

Comment: Dijkstra's algorithm is A* with a constant heuristic.  They are the same w.r.t the requirement for decrease-key -- you need decrease-key for the "standard" implementation, but it's common to get around that by re-inserting nodes.

Comment: @MattTimmermans Thanks, that would answer my question - if you copy that into an answer I'll mark it as accepted; otherwise I'll copy it as an answer myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dijkstra's algorithm is A* with a constant heuristic.

They are the same w.r.t the requirement for decrease-key -- you need decrease-key for the "standard" implementation, but it's common to get around that by re-inserting nodes.